# Will old users get updates if android app is unpublished?

Tags: android, google-play-console

I have an unpublished application in the Play Console. But early this application was published, and some users installed it. Will they receive new updates?

Comment: If the app is unpublished, where would the updates come from?

Comment: I can't add new versions till app is unpublished?

Comment: @CommonsWare when you unpublish an app you can still update it.

Comment: @TheWanderer: Thanks! That's surprising to learn!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. If you unpublish an app, users who already installed it will continue to receive any updates you might send out.

They won't be able to search for the app if they're trying to do a fresh install, but it will appear in their library.

It even says this right below the publish option:

> Note your app will continue to be available to existing users.

If you click "Learn more" you'll see:

> When you unpublish an app, existing users can still use your app and receive app updates. Your app won’t be available for new users to find and download on Google Play.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer.